# what is the range of gini impurity when more than 2 classes?

Tags: machine-learning, decision-tree, entropy, gini

- when we are building a decisiontree, we are usually calculating the gini impurity at each node.
- I am interested to see the range of gini impurity in case of more than 2 classes.
- Because entropy always have range=[0,1], irrespective of number of classes.

I have seen everywhere gin impurity have range=[0, 0.5]. But it is not true in the case of more than 2-classes.

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

- The range of Gini impurity can be calculated by this formula:
  **[0, 1-(1/n)]**
  ,where n is the number of classes.